# Header new.h in application building

Tags: c++, compilation

I encounter a small problem when building an application (which isn't mine)...
My g++ can't find the  header.

`include/utils/Vector.h:20:15: fatal error: new: no shuch file`

and the line 20 of Vector.h:

`#include <new>`

By advance thanks for any answer!

Comment: can you find this header yourself?

Comment: when i'm compiling a small executable created by myself, g++ can find it by itself.... so yeah the <new> header is on my sytem....

Comment: Have you tried writing `#include "new.h"`

Comment: @Ali Modyuhin... as I was saying this project isn't mine i'm here only for testing purpose

Comment: How g++ is being called? Can you paste the whole line?

Comment: You can check if your Makefile contains `-nostdinc` or `-nostdinc++` which will ignore the standard include directory.